# How can I save the defaultValue of an MUI form field to Mongoose?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, material-ui

I have a small nextjs app that uses an MUI form. The form has 2 fields, (1) a default field and (2) an email field. The email is saving fine to the db, but I have issues saving the defaultValue field to mongoose.

I've tried to remove the placeholder and even changed defaultValue to value, but nothing worked yet. I would like to save the defaultValue to mongoose. Kindly the image of the code and form below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anlNN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE3Tb.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly not a way to use `useState` my guy. First, you need to creat a `useState` at the start of the react component function.

```
"use client"
import {useState} from "react"
export default function AComponent(){
  const [fieldVal, setFieldVal] = useState("")
...
}
```

You may then passing the value to the mui textfield value

```
...
<TextField
   ...
   value={fieldVal}
   onChange={e=>setFieldVal(e.target.value)}
   ...
/>
...
```

For another field you will need to declare a different state. You then can use this "fieldVal" to save to mongoose. Remember to save it after it rerenderd to get the latest state though. Hope this can help!

Comment: Thanks, @Hung but it's not about useState because the other field is saving. I am only having issues saving the defaultValue. At least, I want whatever I insert as the defaultValue i.e. `cat` to save.

Comment: @BanjodeIyowun could you please show me the code that you used to save to mongoose?